# c++ win32 popup animation

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating an application that uses popups. However, I would like to animate this popup (a win32 window, a HWND), for example having it slowly extend from the bottom of my screen, moving upwards. Should I make a few dozens of calls to the SetWindowPos function with a small pause in between, or is there a better way to do this, using c++ and win32?

Comment: there are very few things more annoyingly intrusive in a Man-Machine interface than a pop-up... can't you make a status bar or desktop widget, that has consigned space for that info? do you really have to interrupt whatever the user is doing at the moment?

Comment: About the only thing more annoying to me than something popping up in my way is something that animates itself to get there.

Comment: I agree with both of you, however a growl-like notification can be shown without taking focus away from the currently focused window.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but you don't have to worry, my popup shows itself without stealing focus. The user is not interrupted in what he was doing.

Comment: But then you're window isn't really a "popup", but really a "pop-under", so it must be performing some other function than a typical popup does.  Sounds Interesting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use the *[AnimateWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669(VS.85).aspx)* Windows API function.